# Set the margin-top of a div, relative to screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want a `div` to be positioned below the screen, but when you scroll it to appears. I can do this using `margin-top` but this requires a specific number whereas I want it to be relative to the screen it is on, so that it appears when you just start to scroll down on all screens.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: post what you tryed..

Comment: Use position:fixed property to fix the elements on the page.

Comment: Don't use `margin-top`, set `position: absolute` and `bottom` to the negative height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `vh`:

> iewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of viewport, that is the visible portion of the document. Only Gecko-based browsers are updating the viewport values dynamically, when the size of the viewport is modified (by modifying the size of the window on a desktop computer or by turning the device on a phone or a tablet).

```
#myEl {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100vh;
}
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/g8pfow8r/

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled using `position:fixed` and use `top` instead of `margin-top`

```
div {
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, you can use it like that in your javascript, also in `window.resize`

```
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        $("#box").css('position','absolute');
        $("#box").css('top',windowHeight+'px');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm restricted and are not allowed to use Javascript or JQuery

Answer (score 0):

`viewport` values help you define attributes relative to screen size:

```
margin-top:20vw;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqht2u1v/)

Take a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)